# Is there a way to validate that an input is in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I am relatively new to Python. However I am trying to create something to have a user input what state they are currently in and cross-check that the input is valid and is among the states that I have in a list.

However, when I input a valid state when I run it, it still says that the state is invalid on the output. Am I using the "in" operator wrong?

```
DATA_VALID = False  # reset variable from last validation
while DATA_VALID is False: # Loop to ensure input is correct
    STATE = input("What state do live in (in abbreviated form)?") 
    STATE.upper() # Convert input to check later
    STATES = ['AK', 'AL', 'AR', 'AZ', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DC', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA',
              'HI', 'IA', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'MA', 'MD', 'ME',
              'MI', 'MN', 'MO', 'MS', 'MT', 'NC', 'ND', 'NE', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM',
              'NV', 'NY', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX',
              'UT', 'VA', 'VT', 'WA', 'WI', 'WV', 'WY']
    if STATE in STATES:
        DATA_VALID is True
        break
    else:
        print('Please enter a valid state.')
        continue
```

Comment: Maybe you're inputting lower case? in the case your `STATE.upper()` line is not really changing the case of `STATE`, you need to assign it, `STATE = STATE.upper()`. Also you're not setting the `DATA_VALID` variable to true properly, `DATE_VALID = True` not `is True`

Comment: Just as a point of style: variables in Python are typically in `lowercase_snake_case`. `ALL_CAPS` is only used when you're defining a constant, generally for some kind of calculation. If you want to know more, check out [PEP 8 -- The Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: `STATE.upper()` converts `STATE`  to the uppercase but you do not save the converted value. Same with `DATA_VALID is True`. Also, do not use `is`, use `==`. It does not do what you think it does.

Comment: You must type `if STATE.upper() in STATES` instead, since .upper returns a new string instead of changing the current one

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments there are several issues with the above code:

- `STATE.upper()` is not modifying the string in place, you need to assign it: `STATE = STATE.upper()`
- `is` operator indicates if variables point to the same object and is different from both assignment `=` and value equality `==`. In your case use `DATE_VALID = True` instead of `DATE_VALID is True`. But as you will see in the code below, you don't even need this variable
- initialize `STATES` list above the loop as it is not modified inside the loop
- variables are recommended to be in lowercase

With the above points in place, this is the working code:

```
states = ['AK', 'AL', 'AR', 'AZ', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DC', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA',
          'HI', 'IA', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'MA', 'MD', 'ME',
          'MI', 'MN', 'MO', 'MS', 'MT', 'NC', 'ND', 'NE', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM',
          'NV', 'NY', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX',
          'UT', 'VA', 'VT', 'WA', 'WI', 'WV', 'WY']

while True:  # Loop to ensure input is correct
    state = input("What state do live in (in abbreviated form)?")

    state = state.upper()  # Convert input to upper case

    if state in states:
        break
    else:
        print('Please enter a valid state.')
        continue
```